# Changing IP address at runtime

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, vxworks

I am creating a tcp connection using the function `socket()`, `bind()`, and then `listen()`.

Our customers would like to be able to define an IP address of the server at runtime. Is there a way of changing the IP at runtime or must it be done in the BIOS?

Thanks for any tips

Comment: It depends on how the IP is allocated.  If it's static, you can change it locally, but this is somewhat uncommon as it's difficult to manage.  Usually, the IP is supplied by a DHCP server and then things become messy, since persuading the server to issue a new address, (instead of just the same one again), requires bodging the DHCP server config and leases cache:(

Comment: We use a static IP address but would like to add another one. We cannot use DHCP...

Comment: what do you mean **runtime**? hot swap during connection? probably not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the IP address using `ifAddrSet(..)` many times. Usually I call this function from within the startup script before my application is running so I have no idea how calling this function affects already connected sockets.

But have a look at the functions provided by [`ifLib.h`](http://www.vxdev.com/docs/vx55man/vxworks/ref/ifLib.html#ifAddrAdd). I'm sure you'll find something that suits your needs (`ifAddrAdd(..)` looks promising).

Comment: Thanks this was the solution! I am very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by defining 'IP address of the server at runtime?'. Obviously for a given `socket` it's IP address cannot be changed. It's an endpoint of a connection, it cannot be changed run time. If you just want to assign multiple IP addresses to a host that's possible.

In general - you can add as many IP addresses as you want to your machine (ok not exactly) but certainly a hundred or so (ie. statically allocated). That's not the problem (management of that is a nightmare, but sure not impossible). The problem is how those IP addresses are reached, that is not in your control, that depends upon the settings on client especially the routing entries. eg. you could use all of the IP addresses in a Subnet (say `10.1.2/24`).

Not recommended - but possible.

Once you have those IP addresses - you `bind` on the port and address as `INADDR_ANY`, which says accept connection on 'any ' of the local addresses. On which address the connection was made to can be determined on server using `getsockname`.